# hand coded ETL vs talend open studio

Tags: etl, talend

I have developed an ETL with `shell scripting` .

After that,I've found that there's an existing solution `Talend open studio`.
I'm thinking of using  it in my future tasks.

But my problem is that the files that i want to integrate into the database must be transformed in structure . this is the structure that i have :

```
19-08-02  Name                         appel    ok    hope    local  merge   (mk)   
                                                       juin    nov    sept    oct
00:00:t1  T1                            299       0      24      8      3     64
          F2                            119       0      11      8      3     62
          I1                             25       0       2      9      4     64
          F3                            105       0      10      7      3     61
          Regulated F2                    0       0       0
          FR T1                         104       0      10      7      3     61
```

i must transform it into a flat file format .

Do `talend` offer me the possibility to do several transformations before integrating data from `csv`files into the `database`or not ?

**Edit**

this is an example of the flat file that  i want to acheive before integrating data to the database (only first row is concerned) :

```
Timer,T1,F2,I1,F3,Regulated F2,FR T1
00:00:t1,299,119,25,105,0,104  
00:00:t2,649,119,225,165,5,102
00:00:t5,800,111,250,105,0,100
```

Comment: This is exactly what the ETL process is about. Depending on your requirements this might be more or less complex, but possible. It would be easier if you also provided an example of the flat file you want to achieve.

Comment: Is the structure you've got really the source structure in a file, the data is separated with white spaces?

Answer (score 2):

We can split the task into three pieces, extract, transform, load.

**Extract**

First you have to find out how to connect to the source. With Talend its possible to connect to different kinds of sources, like databases, XML files, flat files, csv etc. pp. They are called **tFileInput** or **tMySQLInput** to name a few.

**Transform**

Then you have to tell Talend how to split the data into columns. In your example, this could be the white spaces, although the splitting might be difficult because the field `Name` is also split by a white space.

Afterwards, since it is a column to row transposition, you have to write some Java code in a **tJavaRow** component or could alternatively use a **tMap** component with conditional mapping: `(row.Name.equals("T1") ? row.value : 0)`

**Load**

Then the transformation would be completed and your data could be stored in a database, target file, etc. Components here would be called **tFileOutput** or **tOracleOutput** for example.

**Conclusion**

Yes, it would be possible to build your ETL process in Talend. The transposition could be a little bit complicated if you are new to Talend. But if you keep in mind that Talend processes data row by row (as your script does, I assume) this is not that big of a problem.

Comment: thank you for this beautiful and clear  answer !
I want to know what script langages could `talend ` generate?  only `java`... ?

Comment: You are right, Java code is generated. Generally you never see the Java code, since Talend makes sure to do everything for you. Sometimes you have to add a few pieces of code. Just make sure to have a Java runtime of some kind installed and there you go.